# How can you look for a sequence of words?

Tags: google-keep

Let's say you want to look through your notes and find every note that has exactly "Lorem ipsum" in it. You don't want notes containing only "Lorem" or containing only "ipsum", you want notes that have "Lorem ipsum" exactly like that in the note, two words next to each other. What do you need to enter into the search box to restrict it like that? Is it even possible?

Bonus: Would be interesting to know if you can look for notes containing "Lorem" and "ipsum", but they don't have to be next to each other. So it only gives back notes that contain both "Lorem" and "ipsum".

Comment: did you try CTRL+F ?

Comment: @user902300 If that was a serious question, I find it cute that you assume I only have a few small notes that load into the browser immediatly, and not hundreds of long collapsed notes that only load as you scroll down and only open fully if I click on them. :D

Answer (score 1):

It's actually very simple, just search with quotes to get the exact phrase, or search the words without quotes to get notes that contains both (or more) words, without relevance to the order they appear.

### Examples:

#### Notes:

1. Lorem ipsum
2. Lorem
3. ipsum
4. Lorem something ipsum
5. ipsum something Lorem

#### Searches:

- `Lorem ipsum` will match 1,4,5
- `"Lorem ipsum"` will match 1

#### Demonstartions

[image]

[image] [image]